# Calling POST method from Wcf service item - which path?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I use fiddler to call the method which is post. Here is my path:

```
http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc/MyMethod
```

Everything else is correct. I know the path is wrong. I work in .Net, and I have MVC app with one item which is called MyService.svc.

When the service was in another project I started it, and then called the method. Now, how to start it?

With this pah, I get error 415.

Comment: Can you post some configuration and your service method skeleton that you are using. Also 415 states unsupported media type. Make sure that your service knows the media type it either recieves or sends back to the client

Comment: Have your checked the RouteTable as you are using it in a MVC application. At times the routetable causes such problems if you have not defined your routes properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your service supports REST end-point? If your have configured it as SOAP service then that invoking it with a normal HTTP POST is unlikely to work. The status 415 indicates probably WCF service thinks that its getting invoked with wrong content type.

If it's indeed configured as a REST service (webHttpBiding) then your service host can be wrong - you need to use `WebServiceHost` (or attach webHttpBehavior using configuration) - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/01/wcf-webhttp-service-returns-http-415-unsupported-media-type.aspx